# Current Open Problems Similar to the Basel Problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, open-problem

Are there any current open problems that are similar to the Basel problem?

Comment: Please clarify *similiar to the Basel problem*; if you are asking for the existence of infinite series for which their value is unknown: yes. But that's a very broad question and not really suited for Math.SE.

Comment: This is too vague.  Basel concerns $\zeta (2)$ and, while we do know $\zeta(2n)$, we don't know much about $\zeta(2n+1)$, for instance.  Is that the sort of thing you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The exact value of $\zeta(3)$ is still unknown.

Comment: Well, as this is an irrational number and largely considered as a constant on it's own (the Apéry constant) I wouldn't say the *exact value is still unknown*.

Comment: @mrtaurho: eh... maybe you can put it as not known "in the way like $\zeta(2)$".

Comment: Arguably $\frac{\pi^2}6$ is not any better known than $\zeta(3)$ only because $\pi$ tends to show up more often ;)

Comment: @mrtaurho: unless you are hungry :P